# Is there a plugin that can capture and view 360 degree images in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have searched so much for Flutter plugin, but couldn't find any way in implementation of capturing 360 images in flutter.
imageview360: This plugin only show the 260 degree images

Comment: I'm afraid Flutter currently doesn't have many Panorama libraries for the purpose you are looking for. So you are going to have to use a Android Library alongside the MethodChannel to be able to achieve taking panorama pictures.

There are probably a few Android Panorama libraries or ways to implement it for the use you are looking for.

Comment: You can follow this package "https://pub.dev/packages/panorama"

Answer (score 0):

i published this package [cloudimage_360_view](https://pub.dev/packages/cloudimage_360_view) with more features, check the example app for more details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).